# Flutter Card vs Container Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Can somebody please explain to me the difference between the Flutter card widget & the container widget. They both work the same, have the same properties also looks the same? Why should I use card widget for cards over the container widget

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are familiar with `HTML`, think of containers like divs. They allow you to wrap other content.
On the other hand, `Card` is an implementation of *Material Design*,

> A material design card. A card has slightly rounded corners and a shadow.

A `Card` is a sheet of `Material` used to represent some related information, for example, an album, a geographical location, a meal, contact details, etc.

If you want rounded corners and a shadow then you should definitely use a Card.